# Как поставить quanta plus на Kubuntu 11.10 ?

Tags: kubuntu

Хочу поставить **Quanta plus** на Kubuntu 11.10. В репозиториях пакета нет. Скачал .deb-пакет из хранилища предыдущей версии (11.04).

Ставлю через GDebi, результат - *Error: зависимость не может быть удовлетворена  kdelibs4c2a (>= 4:3.5.9)*.

Пакет kdelibs4c2a в репозиториях не найден.

Как её (эту зависимость) удовлетворить кто-нибудь знает?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в консоли:

```
sudo dpkg -i ваш_quanta_plus_пакет.deb
```

после того, как консоль выдасть сообщение об ошибках с зависимостями, выполните:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```